# Passing a custom filter with attributes to a custom directive in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

Is there a way to pass a custom filter as an attribute into a custom directive? So if I have a directive

```
<my-element value="1234" filter="my-filter:attr1:attr2"><my-element>
```

as

```
angular.module("directives", ["filter"]).directive("myElement", function() {
    return {
    restrict: "E",
        replace : true,
        scope   : {
            value   : "@",
            filter  : "@"
        },
        template: function (el, attr) {
            return "<p>{{value | filter}}</p>";
        },
        link: function($scope){ /* linking stuff */ }
    };
});
```

with a filter:

```
angular.module("filter", []).filter("myFilter", function() {
    return function(value, attr1, attr2) {
            return "filtered value";
        };
    };
});
```

Atm just nothing happens and I don't know what's going wrong here...

Comment: Whats the error? and remove `?` from filter

Comment: have you tried adding transclude: true to your directive? (I admit I still have problems understanding transclusion...)

Comment: I don't get any error, the filter just gets not applied. If I debug the $scope from the linking function it shows that filter is just a string like "filtername:attr"...

Comment: I tried providing a built in filter from angular (currency) by attribute on the custom directive (instead of my own filter), but that doesn't work either (no matter if I use =, ? or @ in the directive scope...) Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible in angular?

Answer (score 0):

Do you inject the two module into your app module? like this:

```
angular.module("app", ["filter","directives"])
```